# Rounding Issue with Quadratic Program

Tags: java

In a problem that I am practicing, the goal is to write the quadratic expression, then round it to the thousandths place. Here is the desired output:

1(a variable) 6(b variable) 3(c variable)

4(a variable) 10(b variable) 6.1(c variable)

Output: 
-0.551, -5.449 (answer for top line)

-1.056, -1.444 (answer for bottom line)

The question is not about how to solve the problem, but instead the answers that I am getting. When computing the quadratic equation as follows:

```
      double a = scan.nextDouble(); 
      double b = scan.nextDouble(); 
      double c = scan.nextDouble(); 

      //equation is correct
      double answer1 = 0.001 * Math.floor((-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)* 1000.0) ;
      double answer2 = 0.001 * Math.floor((-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a) * 1000.0);
```

The answers I am getting are correct, except when I start the rounding to the thousandths place, some numbers are right and others are not even though it looks like they are rounding correctly just not according to the problem.

My Output: 
-0.551, -5.45 
-1.057, -1.444

Is this something to do with how I am rounding? Any help on understanding this rounding issue would be appreciated :)

Comment: *"when I start the **rounding**"* What makes you think that [`Math.floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) does **rounding**? [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) would be the method that does **rounding**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://floating-point-gui.de/languages/java/

How to Round

To get a String:

```
String.format("%.2f", 1.2399) // returns "1.24"
String.format("%.3f", 1.2399) // returns "1.240"
String.format("%.2f", 1.2) // returns "1.20"
```

To print to standard output (or any PrintStream):

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", 1.2399) // same syntax as String.format()
```

If you don’t want trailing zeroes:

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(1.2)// returns "1.20"
new DecimalFormat("0.##").format(1.2)// returns "1.2"
```

If you need a specific rounding mode:

```
new BigDecimal("1.25").setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); // returns 1.2
```

---

And if you do need to round the actual number not just the printed output:

```
  double result = Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
```

where `scale` might be fixed at `1000` for three decimal places or calculated for an arbitrary number of decimal places:

```
  int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
```

Comment: *How to Round:* Use `Math.round()`, not `Math.floor()`

Comment: That would probably help too. :-)  But often when people talk about rounding floating point numbers they actually mean rounding the output, the printed result.