# Java BigDecimal divide and multiply and round to 2 decimals

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a Java BigDecimal expression like below:

```
(totalPrep.divide(totalCase, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)).multiply(new BigDecimal(100))
```

where

BigDecimal totalCase = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal totalPrep = BigDecimal.ZERO;

I have to divide totalPrep with totalCase and the result is multiplied with 100 to get result value in %.
66.6666666666666666666666666666666666667

Say total prep is bidecimal 2 and toalCase is 3,then the math results in 66.6666666666666666666666666666666666667. I want to concat this to 2 decimal places 66.67%

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think BigDecimal is a type of floating point.  You can control the total number of digits of precision, not the places after the decimal.  So there's that little issue to start with.

Comment: So I think normally you end up rounding the output when printed, not the actual number itself.  I just happen to have this handy in my reputation changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121319/rounding-issue-with-quadratic-program/54121348#54121348

Comment: This also might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values

Comment: *FYI:* Since Java 1.5, replace [`BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_UP) with [`RoundingMode.HALF_UP`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP). The old version is deprecated since Java 9.

Comment: As an aside, if this is a percentage split you're not expecting them to always add up to 100...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want `2 / 3` to result in `66.67`, you need to multiply first, *then* divide and round to 2 decimal places:

```java
BigDecimal totalPrep = BigDecimal.valueOf(2);
BigDecimal totalCase = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);

BigDecimal result = totalPrep.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))
                             .divide(totalCase, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.println(result); // prints: 66.67
```

That will calculate `2 * 100 = 200`, then `200 / 3 = 66.67` (rounded)

When you divide first, you calculate `2 / 3 = 0.67` (rounded), then `0.67 * 100 = 67.00`, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Not that it matters but `BigDecimal` has `scaleByPowerOfTen(int n)` which is just a neater way of multiply by 100 with n=2.

Comment: You can also declare ```MathContext mc = new MathContext(4)``` and then use it as such: ```BigDecimal result = totalPrep.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).divide(totalCase,mc);``` Just another way to get the desired output

Comment: @p_flame Can't use `new MathContext(4)`, since we don't know the magnitude of the result. The result should be a percentage with 2 fractional decimals of precision, but since we don't know the actual number of decimals before the decimal point, we don't know what overall precision to use.

Comment: @Persixty I'd prefer `movePointRight(2)` over `scaleByPowerOfTen(2)`. --- `scaleByPowerOfTen` seems redundant given the already existing `movePointRight`, so I wonder why they added the new method in Java 1.5, except that the newer `scaleByPowerOfTen` may cause a negative scale.

Comment: @Andreas Makes no odds here. But it makes more sense to me to admit negative scale in most circumstances. But I'm used to rounding by a negative number of places mean rounding into the integer value. I don't see the decimal point as some kind of boundary. Each as you wish.

Comment: @Persixty I generally don't like scientific notation with positive exponent, i.e. `BigDecimal` with negative scale. I prefer that `5 * 100 = "500"` and `5.movePointRight(2) = "500"`, not the `"5E+2"` result of calling `5.scaleByPowerOfTen(2)` *(where `5` is a BigDecimal of course)*. All just personal preference, I guess.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, it's just your mental model. I think scientific notation makes sense because it works in things like floating point (albeit the exponent is a binary base).